# How to ignore corrupted rows when importing the file to SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there any way to ignore the corrupted lines in a file when importing them to a table using SQLite 3 on Linux? The file size is 13GB and there are around 50 corrupted lines in the file, so manually removing those lines is not easy. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
sqlite> .separator "|"
sqlite> .import myFile.dat myTable
myFile.dat line 29046575: expected 18 columns of data but found 3
```

Comment: I'd use grep ( or fgrep ) to output a clean copy of the file for import and either use the "-v" flag or not depending on whether the regular expression picked matched good or bad lines.

Comment: I can tell you SQLite has no way of doing this, just to confirm. grep sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to sqlite 3.8.10.

It appears 3.7.x is invalidating an entire import when there is a misfit row. 3.8.x appears to print a warning but continue importing.